# Computing the moment-generating function of $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Tags: probability, integration, moment-generating-functions

I have the following in my textbook:
[image: image from textbook]

And I'm trying to verify that $M(t) = (1-t)^{-1}$ on my own. I'm getting: 
$$ f(x) = e^{-x} $$
$$ M(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{tx}f(x) ~dx $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty e^{tx}e^{-x} ~dx $$
$$ = \int_0^\infty e^{x(t - 1)} ~dx $$
$$ = \left. \frac{e^{x(t - 1)}}{t - 1} \right|_{x = 0}^\infty $$
But this appears to be infinity. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147583/compute-the-moment-generating-function-of-x) post where the person evaluates the integral from t=0 to infinity, but if that's correct, I'm not sure why it would be evaluated over the t range and not the x range.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not infinity  because t<1 and the power (t-1)<0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  kmitov says in a comment, $\displaystyle \left. \frac{e^{x(t - 1)}}{t - 1} \right|_{x = 0}^\infty$ is not infinity because $t\lt 1$, and thus $t-1$ is negative and $e^{x(t - 1)}$ tends to $0$ as $x$ increases without limit.

So the integral evaluates to $\dfrac{0}{t-1}-\dfrac{1}{t-1}= \dfrac{1}{1-t}$.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. kmitov's comment was a bit succinct for me to grasp.